# Setting CSS values without units in JS

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm attempting to animate an SVG's `stroke-dashoffset` and `stroke-dasharray` in order to make a "drawing" effect. When setting these values, units need to be relative to the SVG's `width` and `height` HTML attributes, which, in my case, are set separately from its actual size on the document (similar to a Canvas) and thus do not have units. In Chrome, this works fine in JavaScript, using `.style.strokeDashoffset` and `.style.strokeDasharray`. In Firefox, however, I've noticed that these unit-less values are automatically corrected to units of pixels.

I've tried setting values in JS with both individual style variables (as above) and with `.style.cssText` as a whole, to no avail. Is it impossible to have values without units?

```js
function pathAnimate(path) {
  var length = path.getTotalLength();
  path.style.strokeDasharray = length;
  path.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (path.style.strokeDashoffset == "0") {
    path.style.cssText = "stroke-dasharray: " + length + "; stroke-dashoffset: " + length + ";";
  } else {
    path.style.cssText = "stroke-dasharray: " + length + "; stroke-dashoffset: 0;";
  }
}

setInterval(() => {
  pathAnimate(document.querySelectorAll("svg path")[0]);
}, 1000)
```

```css
svg path {
  stroke: #696969;
  stroke-width: 16;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  fill: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <svg width="371.43532" height="473.79655" viewbox="0 0 371.43532 473.79655">
    <path d="m 179.29563,388.2732 -0.71909,-227.11466 c -0.12011,-37.93426 41.87061,-39.6739 41.87061,0 v 189.77189 c 0,35.61587 43.29422,38.0718 43.76053,0 l 2.32434,-189.77189 c 0.8842,-72.190591 19.29427,-107.190071 63.3958,-155.7820307" />
    </svg>
</body>
```

*Note: this snippet works in Chrome, as I explain above.*

Comment: I know that I can calculate the actual values using attributes like `offsetWidth`, or write CSS animations for each element, but I really just want to easily be able to do this in JavaScript.

Comment: Not in Chrome, apparently. The relative units seem to work fine… am I misinterpreting something at the browser level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use parseFloat to strip any units.

Per [the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#Units) omitted units are the same as pixels. CSS in general wants units even if SVG is more laissez faire about such things.

> One px unit is defined to be equal to one user unit. Thus, a length of "5px" is the same as a length of "5".

```js
function pathAnimate(path) {
  var length = path.getTotalLength();
  path.style.strokeDasharray = length;
  if (parseFloat(path.style.strokeDashoffset, 10) == 0) {
    path.style.cssText = "stroke-dasharray: " + length + "; stroke-dashoffset: " + length + ";";
  } else {
    path.style.cssText = "stroke-dasharray: " + length + "; stroke-dashoffset: 0;";
  }
}

setInterval(() => {
  pathAnimate(document.querySelectorAll("svg path")[0]);
}, 1000)
```

```css
svg path {
  stroke: #696969;
  stroke-width: 16;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  fill: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <svg width="371.43532" height="473.79655" viewbox="0 0 371.43532 473.79655">
    <path d="m 179.29563,388.2732 -0.71909,-227.11466 c -0.12011,-37.93426 41.87061,-39.6739 41.87061,0 v 189.77189 c 0,35.61587 43.29422,38.0718 43.76053,0 l 2.32434,-189.77189 c 0.8842,-72.190591 19.29427,-107.190071 63.3958,-155.7820307" />
    </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: So, my "relative units" issue wasn't the real problem; scaling the SVG doesn't affect the offsets.